# I am having trouble in changing the manager_id column name as Supervisor and employee_id column name as Employee

Tags: mysql

```
select  concat(m.first_name, ' ' , m.last_name ) manager_id, 
    concat(e.first_name,  ' ' , e.last_name ) employee_id    

 from employees e 
 left join employees m on m.employee_id = e.manager_id

 order by manager_id;
```

Comment: You need the AS keyword, after the select concat(m.first_name, ' ' , m.last_name ).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(m.first_name, ' ' , m.last_name ) AS mgr_Fullname,
manager_id AS Supervisor,
CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ' , e.last_name ) AS emp_Fullname,
employee_id AS Employee FROM employees e LEFT JOIN employees m
ON m.employee_id = e.manager_id ORDER BY manager_id;
```